# How can I use action item as a button in android programming?

Tags: java, android

I have a menu upside my page and it has an action item. like this:

[action item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3z5Fs.png)

I set `app:showAsAction="always"` for it.

I have invisible view (in UI) in my page too.

I want to if I click on it, my invisible view appears. so I set a boolean parameter for that. 
My boolean set true but my object doesn't appear at all. How can I fix it?

here is my code:

```
    public static boolean myBoolean=false;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //this if doesn't check after change parameter
    if(myBoolean)
       findViewById(R.id.checkBox).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_setting: {
            myBoolean=true;
            return true;
        }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I am getting from this is you want to show a view based on the click of some menu item in action bar right?. if this is true then do like this.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_setting:
        if(myBoolean){
           findViewById(R.id.checkBox).setVisibility(View.GONE);
           myBoolean = false;
        }else{
           findViewById(R.id.checkBox).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           myBoolean = true;
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

you can't decide the visibility earlier in your code since click may happen sometime after onCreate() only.

Comment: that is right,thanks. But when I set myBoolean true in button onclick in onCreate(), it check all the time (my setVisible stay is in onCreate and out of onClick button) why is this?